# An isoperimetric type of inequality in terms of Wasserstein distance/Optimal transport

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, geometric-measure-theory, isoperimetric-problems, optimal-transportation

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a region having the same volume as an $n$ dimensional ball $B^n_R$ with radius $R$ centring at the origin.
Isoperimetric inequality says:
$ Vol_{n-1} \partial A \geq Vol_{n-1} S^{n-1}_R $, where $S^{n-1}_R$ is the corresponding $n-1$ sphere.

I'm thinking of the following variation in terms of Wasserstein distance, $W_p$ (a better name is perhaps iso-Wasserstein distance inequality, if it were true). Let $B^n_r$ be another $n$ ball with radius $r \leq R$ centring at origin. 
Is it true that for all regions $A$ such that:
$$ Vol_{n} A = Vol_{n} B^n_R $$
we have 
$$ W_p(\mathbb{P}(A), \mathbb{P}(B^n_r)) \geq W_p(\mathbb{P}(B^n_R), \mathbb{P}(B^n_r)) $$
where $\mathbb{P}$ denotes a uniform probability distribution on a region, i.e. $\mathbb{P}(A)$ has density $\frac{1}{Vol_{n} A}$.

Comment: For $R \leq r$, this seems reasonable. But for $R > r$, I feel there should be a counterexample in one dimension, where $B_R^n$ is the line segment $[-R,R]$ and we should be able to violate the inequality by "spacing out" $A$ evenly throughout $[-R,R]$. (For instance let $A$ be the union of two line segments of length $r/2$, one centered in $[-R,0]$ and the other centered in $[0,R]$.)

Comment: Probably I'm missing something basic or my formulation is misleading, if $A$ is the union of two line segments with length $r/2$ (so length of $A$ is $r$, which is $ < 2R$), wouldn't it violate the condition that length of $A = 2R$, as this is the length of $[-R, R]$

Comment: sorry, I mixed up $r$ and $R$. I'm thinking of the case $r > R$, and $A$ is the union of two line segments of length $R/2$, centered in $[-r,0]$ and on $[0,r]$.

Comment: Cool. It was the initial case that I'm interested. But when I typed it, I didn't see the constraint being necessary. Thanks for the counter-example. I will edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

we could assume $r=1$

The best shape of $A$ should be rotation invariant and become $B_R$ when $R \geq 1.$ and cant be obtained when $R\leq 1.$

By rotation and the convex of Wasserstein distance, we could replace the probability distribution $P(A)$ by distribution $\mu$ which is invariant under rotation transformation, and $\mu$ should satisfies a simple constrains,i.e.
$$d\mu =wfr^{n-1}dS^{n-1} , \int d\mu =1 , f\leq \frac{1}{R}$$
where $w$ the area of $S^{n-1}$,.
After above simplication, it is also resonable to reduce this problem to the case $n=1$,and measure ssupported on $ R^+.$ and consider the Wasserstein distance between distribution $a$ and $b$ with 
$$ a=wr^{n-1}X_{[0,1]} ,b=wr^{n-1}f,f\leq \frac{1}{R} $$

For $R\leq 1$, $f= X_{[0,1]}$,and you could approximated $A$ by union infinity small balls dense in $B_1$.

For $R\geq 1$, $f= X_{[0,R]}$,and $A$ should be $B_R$.

Comment: my first answer is false, and thi is the right answer